# How to group unique tags in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

I have a table like this:

```
GROUPID | TAG 
------  | ------
1       | Tag1 Tag2
1       | Tag1 Tag3
1       | Tag1 Tag4 
2       | Tag5 Tag6
2       | Tag4 Tag3
```

And I want to get the following results:

```
GROUP   | TAG
------- | -------
1       | Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 Tag4
2       | Tag3 Tag4 Tag5 Tag6
```

And ideas how to filter the duplicated Tags in oracle SQL ?

Thanks

Comment: Bad idea all around. What does "I have" mean - is the input data (your first table) a stored table, on disk? What does "result" mean - what is displayed for reporting purposes? If so, then perhaps getting the report in that format is OK, but the base data violates one of the most basic principles of relational table design. So basic, in fact, that it's called "First Normal Form." The best solution in all such cases is to normalize your data - if you can't in the database, then at least in your query.

Comment: Jack does your data always have two tags per GroupId per row, or any number of tags per row?

Comment: it would be any tags per row.  And it could be empty also.  Thanks. -Jack

Comment: And in the result, the tags do not need to be in any alphabetically order. I was just give an example.  Thanks. -Jack

Comment: What is TAG column type ?

Comment: It is "varchar(4000)". Thanks, -Jack

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I added an initial set of examples with the provided data, but these assume everything is case-sensitive in form Tag#.  Does this assumption hold true?  Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not. each Tag value can be any string value.

Comment: Thanks @user3595231 for the clarification.  I'll update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As mathguy mentioned in comments, queries like this can be simplified by changes to the design.
But given the data in this format, one can still extract a unique set of `TAG` per `GROUPID`.  Here's an example approach:

In this first stage, we will use `REGEXP_COUNT` to see how many `TAG`s each row has.  Then we'll *generate* positional tag-numbers for each `TAG` in each row.  Finally we'll extract the tag at a given position for each conglomerated`TAG` in each row.

First, create the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE GROUPID_TAG(
  GROUPID NUMBER,
  "TAG" VARCHAR2(256)
);

INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (1,'Tag1 Tag2');
INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (1,'Tag1 Tag3');
INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (1,'Tag1 Tag4');
INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (2,'Tag5 Tag6');
INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (2,'Tag4 Tag3');
```

The below query will generate two columns, with a single `TAG` in the `ONLY_ONE_TAG` column (but more rows per `GROUPID`)

```
WITH COUNTED_TAG AS (
   SELECT GROUPID, "TAG", REGEXP_COUNT("TAG",'(^| )[^ ]{1,}') AS TAG_COUNT FROM GROUPID_TAG),
    KEYED_COUNTED_TAG AS (
     SELECT GROUPID, "TAG", TAG_COUNT, TAG_KEG_GENERATOR.TAG_KEY FROM COUNTED_TAG
       INNER JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS TAG_KEY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 999) TAG_KEG_GENERATOR
         ON TAG_KEG_GENERATOR.TAG_KEY <= COUNTED_TAG.TAG_COUNT)
SELECT DISTINCT GROUPID, REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR("TAG",'(^| )[^ ]{1,}',1,TAG_KEY),' ','') AS ONLY_ONE_TAG
FROM KEYED_COUNTED_TAG
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

Running it gives:

```
GROUPID  ONLY_ONE_TAG  
1        Tag1          
1        Tag2          
1        Tag3          
1        Tag4          
2        Tag3          
2        Tag4          
2        Tag5          
2        Tag6
```

The data at this point may be easier to work with than in its original state.  But if you want to re-aggregate into one row per GROUPID, here's an example of that.  Starting with our last query, we'll add a `LISTAGG` to aggregate things:

```
WITH COUNTED_TAG AS (
   SELECT GROUPID, "TAG", REGEXP_COUNT("TAG",'(^| )[^ ]{1,}') AS TAG_COUNT FROM GROUPID_TAG),
    KEYED_COUNTED_TAG AS (
     SELECT GROUPID, "TAG", TAG_COUNT, TAG_KEG_GENERATOR.TAG_KEY FROM COUNTED_TAG
       INNER JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS TAG_KEY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 999) TAG_KEG_GENERATOR
         ON TAG_KEG_GENERATOR.TAG_KEY <= COUNTED_TAG.TAG_COUNT),
    DISTINCT_TAG AS(SELECT DISTINCT GROUPID, REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR("TAG",'(^| )[^ ]{1,}',1,TAG_KEY),' ','') AS ONLY_ONE_TAG
                    FROM KEYED_COUNTED_TAG)
SELECT GROUPID, LISTAGG(ONLY_ONE_TAG,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONLY_ONE_TAG ASC) AS AGGREGATED_TAG
FROM DISTINCT_TAG
GROUP BY GROUPID
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Result:

```
GROUPID  AGGREGATED_TAG       
1        Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 Tag4  
2        Tag3 Tag4 Tag5 Tag6
```

Then, add some additional tags, for testing:

```
INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (1,'Wookie    Hobbit @_@');
INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (2,'HAL-9000  Thor');
```

And query again:

```
WITH COUNTED_TAG AS (
   SELECT GROUPID, "TAG", REGEXP_COUNT("TAG",'(^| )[^ ]{1,}') AS TAG_COUNT FROM GROUPID_TAG),
    KEYED_COUNTED_TAG AS (
     SELECT GROUPID, "TAG", TAG_COUNT, TAG_KEG_GENERATOR.TAG_KEY FROM COUNTED_TAG
       INNER JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS TAG_KEY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 999) TAG_KEG_GENERATOR
         ON TAG_KEG_GENERATOR.TAG_KEY <= COUNTED_TAG.TAG_COUNT),
    DISTINCT_TAG AS(SELECT DISTINCT GROUPID, REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR("TAG",'(^| )[^ ]{1,}',1,TAG_KEY),' ','') AS ONLY_ONE_TAG
                    FROM KEYED_COUNTED_TAG)
SELECT GROUPID, LISTAGG(ONLY_ONE_TAG,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONLY_ONE_TAG ASC) AS AGGREGATED_TAG
FROM DISTINCT_TAG
GROUP BY GROUPID
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Result:

```
GROUPID  AGGREGATED_TAG                         
1        @_@ Hobbit Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 Tag4 Wookie  
2        HAL-9000 Tag3 Tag4 Tag5 Tag6 Thor
```

Comment: Thanks. But somehow, this sql will

Comment: Thanks @user3595231  It looks like your comment cut off.  Did you mean this sql will not execute for you?  What version of Oracle are you using?  Can you include the exception you get?  Thanks

Comment: If the TAG in GROUPID_TAG TABLE contains more then 2 TAGS, I see some strange results.  This is what I have  added "INSERT INTO GROUPID_TAG VALUES (2,'AAA BBB CCC DDD'); COMMIT", And running that sql, the result only gave me part of TAGS for "2" Group.  -Jack.

Comment: Thanks @user3595231.  That looks like a bug in my example.  Just one second; I'll update.

Comment: Thanks @user3595231.  Yeah I was missing the start index on `regexp_substr`.  Can you try again with the update and let me know?  Thanks

Comment: Beautiful ! This SQL works perfectly for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks @user3595231 This post is still fairly new so you may want to wait for other answers, but if your question has been answered (by this post or another) please consider accepting an answer; it helps to know the state of things.  Thanks